# How can I place an line text from a file into an textbox?

Tags: c#

What I would like to do is the following:

I have a couple of text boxes that needs to be filled with a file line. The lines of the file are generated elsewhere, some numbers places individually on a new line. What I would like to do is when the Form is opened;

1. The file needs to read
2. The values needs to be placed in an array
3. The array items needs to placed in the text boxes.

I've tried the following:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file_path");

Textbox1.Value = lines[0];
Textbox1.Value = lines[1];
Textbox1.Value = lines[2];
Textbox1.Value = lines[3];
```

Then the error is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'.
So I have to convert that string to a decimal but how?

Comment: `Textbox1.Text = lines[0];`? `Textbox1.Value =   Decimal.Parse(lines[0]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
Textbox1.Text= lines[0];
```

instead of

```
Textbox1.Value = lines[0];
```

Comment: Omg like that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use decimal's `Parse` extension method.

```
decimal.Parse(lines[0]);
...
```